How to hide method for certain instances
I'm having controller that initialize communication with a card.
Both read and write use the same communication class but I want to restrict the read properties to Read() method and the write properties to Write() methods.
Example:
public sealed class Communicator
{
    public int Port { get; private set; }
    public int Bit { get; private set; }

    public Communicator(int port, int bit)
    {
        Port = port;
        Bit = bit;
    }

    public long Read()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public long write(bool[] values)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public sealed class ReadWrite()
{
    public Communicator PortRead1 => new(0, 2);
    public Communicator PortRead2 => new(3, 5);
    public Communicator PortRead3 => new(6, 7);

    public Communicator PortWrite1 => new(1, 5);
    public Communicator PortWrite2 => new(1, 5);
    public Communicator PortWrite3 => new(1, 5);
}

Is there any why to make the Read() method visible only to the reads properties inside the ReadWrite class and the Write() method to the writes properties?

Do the properties of the ReadWrite class have to return a Communicator? If not, you could use (and return) interfaces like IReadableCommunicator and IWritableCommunicator instead.

How are you going to synchronize writings into same port? You may want to rename Communicator to PropertyCommunicator, make it aware about property writeability and throw in Write method.

@Sinatr They won't access the same port, but the access method is the same for read or write.
ipodtouch0218 gave me the solution I was needed, Thanks!


Is there any why to make the Read() method visible only to the reads properties inside the ReadWrite class and the Write() method to the writes properties?

No, the solution is to use different types. Some possible options:
Separate classes with an interface
Suitable if there is little shared code between reading and writing
public interface ICommunicator{
    public int Port { get;  }
    public int Bit { get; }
}
public sealed class ReadCommunicator(int port, int bit) : ICommunicator
{
    public int Port { get;  } = port;
    public int Bit { get; } = bit;

    public long Read()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
public sealed class WriteCommunicator(int port, int bit) : ICommunicator
{
    public int Port { get;  } = port;
    public int Bit { get; } = bit;

    public long write(bool[] values)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

Common base class
May be suitable if there the base communicator has some public API that it needs to expose. Note that while inheritance has some uses, the general recommendation is "composition over inheritance".
public class Communicator(int port, int bit) {
    public int Port { get;  } = port;
    public int Bit { get; } = bit;
}
public sealed class ReadCommunicator : Communicator
{
    public ReadCommunicator(int port, int bit) : base(port, bit){}

    public long Read()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
public sealed class WriteCommunicator : Communicator
{
    public WriteCommunicator (int port, int bit): base(port, bit){}
    public long write(bool[] values)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

Wrappers
May be suitable if the Reader/writer uses a higher level of abstraction than the plain communicator.
public sealed class ReadCommunicator 
{
    private Communicator communicator;
    public ReadCommunicator(Communicator communicator) => this.communicator = communicator;
    public long Read() => communicator.Read();
}
public sealed class WriteCommunicator : Communicator
{
    private Communicator communicator;
    public WriteCommunicator (Communicator communicator) => this.communicator = communicator;
    public long write(bool[] values) => communicator.Write(values);
}

Separate interfaces
may be suitable if you are using dependency injection or other patterns that ensure you are always using interfaces.
public interface ICommunicator{
    public int Port { get;  }
    public int Bit { get; }
}
public interface IReadCommunicator : ICommunicator{
    long Read();
}
public interface IWriteCommunicator : ICommunicator{
    long write(bool[] values);
}
public class Communicator : IReadCommunicator, IWriteCommunicator {
   ...
}

